# Mysql query to find first using IN clause with preference from left to right

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, in-clause, findfirst

I have a test table with columns(id, title, language)

id: primary_key (auto-increment)

unique_key(composite) on language and title

| id | title | language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Japanese | JP |
| 2 | Australian | AU |
| 3 | English | EN |
| 4 | Hindi | HI |

I would like to have a query which either return 1 or 0 rows based on the multiple language criteria.

The query should return the result with language priority from left to right, if no row found for first language from left then look for the second language as so on.

Use-case:

| languages | result row_id | remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JP,HI | 1 | As JP found at id=1 |
| HI,JP | 4 | As HI found at id=4 |
| RU,AU | 2 | As AU found at id=2, no row with language=RU |
| PK,ST | no row | As no language has value PK or ST |

Here's I've tried custom order using `FIELD` clause on language column:

```
SELECT id, title, language
    FROM test WHERE language IN ('TH', 'AU','EN') ORDER BY 
FIELD(LANGUAGE,'TH','AU','EN') LIMIT 1;
```

Expected/Actual output:

| id | title | language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Australian | AU |

I would like to know is there any better way(in terms of **performance** and **readability**) to achieve this use-case?

Comment: *in terms of performance...* That kind of searching within a string isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert languages list to rowset:

```sql
SELECT test.id, test.title, language
FROM test 
JOIN (SELECT 'TH' language, 1 priority UNION ALL
      SELECT 'AU'         , 2          UNION ALL
      SELECT 'EN'         , 3          ) languages USING (language)
ORDER BY languages.priority LIMIT 1;
```

---

> for 8+, the parameter format would be csv – Another coder

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
parameter AS (
    SELECT @languages_as_CSV CSV
),
languages AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(CSV, ',', 1) language, 
           SUBSTRING(CSV FROM 1 + LOCATE(',', CSV)) tail,
           1 priority
    FROM parameter
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(tail, ',', 1),
           SUBSTRING(tail FROM 1 + LOCATE(',', tail))
    FROM cte
    WHERE tail <> ''
)
SELECT test.id, test.title, language
FROM test 
JOIN languages USING (language)
ORDER BY languages.priority LIMIT 1;
```

I.e. recursive CTE parses CSV to separate values and adds priority data. Then the same query is executed, and parsed rowset is used instread of static languages list.

`@languages_as_CS` is a placeholder for a parameter which provides CSV languages list into the query.

Pay attention - none excess chars. `'TH,AU,EN'` and not `'TH, AU, EN'`.

Comment: thanks for the solution, it also works fine. As the language criteria can be dynamic, so sub-query would vary based on the number of languages. Is it possible to handle the query in a dynamic way?

Comment: @Anothercoder *Is it possible to handle the query in a dynamic way?* Of course. What is precise MySQL version? What is maximal (in theory in future) languages amount?

Comment: MySQL version is `5.7.30` but I will upgrade the version to `8.0.25` in near future. And maximal amount of languages would be around 8-10.

Comment: @Anothercoder For 5.x the solution will contain static table with numbers 1-10... do you need in such solution really? or maybe the solution for 8+ is enough? And - what format of languages list provided into the query as a parameter is more convenient for you - CSV or JSON array?

Comment: For 5.x using static table, I can give a try by myself. And for 8+, the parameter format would be csv

Answer (score 0):

See if this will help:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE    FIND_IN_SET(language, languages)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(language, languages)
```

FIND_IN_SET will return the empty set if there is no match, so something extra is needed to handle the "0" case.

Comment: *FIND_IN_SET will return the **empty set** if there is no match* This is not correct. The function returns the searching string position in the strings list (as UNSIGNED INTEGER, it seems), and it returns **zero** value when the value to be searched for is not found.